# How to mandate all the users in a group to grant permissions to my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I'm trying to read the comments made on my posts in a group. But I cant really read

> {comment-id}?fields=from

Unless the user grants permission to my app I'm unable to fetch the from field on the comment.

How can I force the group members to grant permission to my app.

Comment: please do not create separate threads for the same issue.

Comment: @luschn This would be a seperate tread as on my other post I wanted the email field for users who have commented, and here I need how I can make it a mandate for all the members of a group. I added group tag here but I did not add page tag.

Please remove the duplicate tag from this question as it only pertains to groups

Comment: you asked that question in the other thread too, so there is no point in adding a new one. it is around the same problem anyway.

Comment: _“How can I force the group members to grant permission to my app.”_ - you can’t.